# For long vs for a long time

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is the use of "for long" to mean "for a long time " restricted to only negative sentences and questions ?
Example 
He couldn't tolerate it for long. 
Did he tolerate it for long ? 
Can I say **he tolerated it for long**?

Comment: You certainly can't say *He tolerated it for long.* I'm not 100% sure off the top of my head, but I suspect you can only use ***for long*** in ***negating*** contexts (or as you say, in questions: *Will you be gone for long?*). That restriction doesn't apply to similar forms such as *He's been gone **for weeks***.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  We can say "_He's been gone for **too long**_", "_He hasn't been gone **for too long**_" and "_He hasn't been gone **for long**_" but we would never say "_He's been gone **for long**_". I can't think of any examples where we would use **for long** in a positive context but I can't think of a good reason why we wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to CGEL*, you seem to be right about *for long* not being able to be used in positive declarative sentences.

> (1) *They didn’t laugh loudly or for long.*
>
> (2) *No one laughs for long.*
>
> (3) *Few people laughed for long.*
>
> (4) *I doubt that he’ll laugh for long.*
>
> (5) *Did they laugh for long?*
>
> (6) *I’ll leave if they laugh for long.*
>
> ...
>
> As we see, *for long* does not have to be preceded by not or a negative auxiliary; it merely has to be in some sort of non-affirmative context.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston and Pullum (Page 825).

Comment: The 6th sentence appears to be affirmative.  What do you think?

Comment: I just found this https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives/long

Comment: @user271640 Although the subordinate clause (_they laugh for long_) in (6) is positive, it is not used to assert a positive proposition: the proposition is merely conditionally entertained. That's just like you can use _any longer_ in _I’ll leave if they laugh any longer._

Comment: @user271640 I don't know what you're trying to say with your link.

Comment: The link says "We don’t use long on its own in affirmative clauses. We often use (for) a long time" which is in agreement with  your answer.